# Rich modalpanel closes automatically

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I face the same issue as described here [Rich modalpanel closes automatically](http://community.jboss.org/message/49659?tstart=0)

I'm using richfaces 3.3.0 (Included in seam 2.12). I tried to isolate the problem, Firebug shows that after the modalpanel shows up, a request to the server is generated. And the panel closes after a few ms. I treied several locations for the rich_modalPanel tag (inside the form outside).

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib">
<head />
<body id="pgHome">
<f:view>
    <div id="document">
        <h:form id="login">
        <fieldset>
            <h:outputLabel id="UsernameLabel" for="username">Login Name</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="username" value="#{identity.username}" style="width: 175px;" />
        </fieldset>
        <h:commandButton id="search2" value="modal"
            onclick="#{rich:component('mp')}.show()" />

        </h:form> 
        <rich:modalPanel id="mp" height="200" width="500">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Modal Panel Title" />
            </f:facet>
        </rich:modalPanel>
    </div>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

I finally used this example:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="modalPanelID">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="header" />
    </f:facet>
    <a onclick="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('modalPanelID');" href="#">Hide</a>
</rich:modalPanel>
<a onclick="Richfaces.showModalPanel('modalPanelID');" href="#">Show</a>
```

Comment: Is the panel supposed to open when you push the button, as declaed in `onclick="#{rich:component('mp')}.show()"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behavior is normal, as you display your `ModalPanel` using the commandButton using the following code:

```
<h:commandButton id="search2" value="modal" onclick="#{rich:component('mp')}.show()" />
```

The `commandButton` will display the `ModalPanel`, and **then** will submit the form. This will force the page to be redisplayed completely, and that's why you get this behavior.

To solve your problem, you must `return false;` at the end of the `onclick` event, which can be translated to *Display the Modal Panel and then stop any processing, i.e. do NOT submit the form*. The code to use is the following:

```
<h:commandButton id="search2" value="modal" onclick="#{rich:component('mp')}.show(); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `<a4j:commandButton>` instead of `<h:commandButton>`.

But since you are just having `onclick`, you don't need a `commandButton` at all - use an `<input type="button" onclick=".." />`

Comment: That will still post the form and result in the same behavior

Comment: @Shervin no it won't. `<a4j:commandButton` invokes the `action` with ajax.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that since you are using `h:commandButton` you are posting the form, and unless this is what you want to do, then that's the problem.

At least make the button return false so it doesn't post, or use a normal html button.

Comment: +1 Thanks, sorry that I didn't understand what you meant by 'return false' since romaintaz answers work, it is right.

Answer (score 0):

I have a smiliar problem. I use a commandButton for uploading a file. Using the onClick-Event fires the event without clicking on loading the page. If I use the action my modal panel hides automatically. After clicking the commandButton the modalPanel should stay open. I need the submit of the form to handle the uploaded data in the bean.

Here is my code...

```
<h:commandButton id="Button"
    process="@this,attachmentPanel"
    binding="#{actionButton}"
    value="#{messages['view.attachment.add']}"
    action="#{myHandler.addAttachment()}"
    reRender="attachmentFramePanel">
</h:commandButton>
```